# Exporting an artboard as SVG messes up the artboard's images

Tags: sketch-app

When I export an artboard as an SVG, it messes up the images on the artboard.

Why does this happen?

**Example of the SVG and PNG files:**

**ChooseSize.svg (the images are washed out and color is skewed)**

[image]

**MyFile.png (the images are correct)**
[image]

Comment: I don't use sketch so can't say anything specific about that but are you using blending modes?

Comment: I would suggest exporting images in PNG as you can size them to 3x, 2x and 1x which works for both app and websites.